# Oracle SQL Foreign Key Issues

Tags: oracle, reference, foreign-keys

I am trying to create tables as well as references but keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR at line 4: 
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

...and have searched high and low with no clear way on how to resolve this. I have the following:

```
drop table financing_plans;
CREATE TABLE financing_plans (plan_id     CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
                        institution       VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
                        Loan_type      VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
                        min_down          NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL,
                        max_loan_amount            NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL,
                        Percentage           NUMBER(10,2)      NOT NULL,
                        Max_term        NUMBER(10,25)      NOT NULL);
```

drop table sale_financings;

```
CREATE TABLE sale_financings (sale_id     CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
                        Down_pay       VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
                        Loan_term      VARCHAR2(18) NOT NULL,
                        FOREIGN KEY ("plan_uid") REFERENCES financing_plans(plan_id)
                        FOREIGN KEY ("sale_uid") REFERENCES sales(sale_id));
```

drop table sales;

```
CREATE TABLE sales (sale_id     CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
                        Salesperson_ID       VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
                        Cust_ID      VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
                        VIN          VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
                        Gross_sale_price            NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL,
                        Mileage           NUMBER(10,2)      NOT NULL,
                        sale_date        DATE,
                        Vehicle_status      VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL);
```

Any solution, anyone?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create columns for the foreign key at first, and then create the foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE financing_plans (
  plan_id CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
, institution VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL
, Loan_type VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
, min_down NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL
, max_loan_amount NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL
, Percentage NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL
, Max_term NUMBER(10,25) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE sales (
  sale_id CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
, Salesperson_ID VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL
, Cust_ID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
, VIN VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
, Gross_sale_price NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL
, Mileage NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL
, sale_date DATE
, Vehicle_status VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE sale_financings (
  sale_id CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
, Down_pay VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL
, Loan_term VARCHAR2(18) NOT NULL
, plan_id char(10) not null
, sale_uid char(10) not null
, CONSTRAINT constraint_name_fk FOREIGN KEY (plan_id) REFERENCES financing_plans(plan_id)
, constraint constraint_name_fk2 foreign key (sale_uid) references sales(sale_id)
);
```

Comment: Genius! It worked flawlessly. I have now been able to create all the tables I needed. One thing I was also wondering is how do I insert into a table that has a foreign key since it is supposed to populate from the content of the table with the primary key. I am unsure how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating the FK reference to sales(sale_id) in sale_financings before you create the sales table. Also, I would check to be sure table exits before dropping it.